# Using a checkbox and onListItemClick in listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-view

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a checkbox in each row, having the ability to check the box separately (for batch deleting) and being able to select the entire row to view data associated with the list item.

I have done a checkbox with a textview but that only lets be select the box and I cant click on the list item to view that items data. I also used `checkedTextView` but that checks the box where ever you click on the row calling the `onListItemClick` and thats not what I want either. Is there some what I can separate checking the box from clicking a listview item?

Pretty much trying to do what the `gmail` app does when selecting messages to delete and view

this is my row layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameCheckTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

creating listview

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state){
        super.onActivityCreated(state);
        lv = getListView();
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        setEmptyText("No Bowlers");       
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        populateList();
    }
```

**EDIT:**

my populate method

```
public void populateList(){

        String[] fields = new String[] {BowlersDB.NAME};
        //mAdapter = new CheckAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.check_listview,null,fields,new int[] {R.id.nameCheckTV});
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.check_listview,null,fields,
            new int[] {R.id.nameCheckTV});
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);         
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
    }
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to set an onItemClickListener for your ListView that will start another activity with the info of the row selected when the row is clicked (outside the CheckBox of course). I would recommend having your Activity implement `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` which requires the method

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {}
```

Inside this method you can launch an Activity with details corresponding to the data in the row selected.
Hopefully I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 13):

The issue is that Android doesn't allow you to select list items that have elements on them that are focusable. Try modifying the checkbox on the list item:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, took me quite some time to figure it out.

Comment: @Alex Lockwood Thank you so much. took me hell lot of time to find this solution.

Comment: Yes this works for me too! Make this the accepted answer please!

Answer (score 0):

I had a strange workaround with this issue.  Here is my solution.

Use this for your ListView.  Product is just a model object to hold your data in this case:

```
public class CatalogItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> //
{
private ArrayList<Product> products;
private Activity activity;

public CatalogItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Product> items, Activity activity) //
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.products = items;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) //
{
    Product product = products.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) //
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.catalog_item_stub, null, false);
    }
}
}
```

Somewhere in your `onResume()`, put this:

```
listView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.CatalogProducts);

m_adapter = new CatalogItemAdapter(activity,
            R.layout.catalog_item_stub, products, activity);

if (products == null)
        products = new ArrayList<Product>();

listView.setAdapter(m_adapter);
```

`R.layout.catalog_item_stub` is a layout stub created in XML like so (put the appropriate items in it for you, like the checkbox):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/catalog_item_stub"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="90dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="5dp">
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:weightSum="5"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right">
    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="product_title" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/ProductTitle" android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.5" android:textColor="#000000" />
    <CheckBox android:padding="5dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="select" android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/chkSelect"
        android:layout_weight="1.5" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hopefully this helps!  Holler if you need any clarification.

Comment: I guess I am a little confused about how this gets around the problem of not having 2 different selection options?

Comment: You can use your own custom elements and do whatever you want with them.  This means you can handle everything manually and have it behave as you like.

Comment: @tyczj take a look at the small change I made.  It should make it a little more clear what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The gmail app uses its own view called CanvasConversationHeaderView that manages its subviews. This method is probably more heavy-weight than what you are looking for.

An easier method would be to make the checkbox not "focusable" (as Alex Lockwood suggests) and then attach an onClick in the XML.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
```

Then in your activity code add

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)view.getParent();
    Log.d(TAG, "Checkbox clicked! getTag returned: " + rl.getTag());
}
```

EDIT: How to add a tag from SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView

```
private class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Cursor pos: " + cursor.getPosition());
        String name = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        view.setTag(name);
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
    }
}
```

Note: I set the tag to the View from the bindView call, which is the RelativeLayout at the root of your xml. Look at the onCheckboxClicked method to see how I got the tag.

Comment: I did try using an onClick method at first but I cant get the id of the items selected for deletion. The only way I would be able to do that is to set a listener on the checkbox in my adapter and keep a running array of id's

Comment: You can try using the view's setTag and getTag methods for attaching meaning to each one. In your ListAdapter when you populate the row, just add view.setTag(new Integer(position)). (Note that this would set the tag of the RelativeLayout, so you can either do a view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1).setTag() or in the onClick you can get the parent of the checkBox to get the relativeLayout that owns the checkbox.)

Comment: I use a cursor to populate the listview from a database though, would that change anything? also updated first post with my populate list method

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but you could override the cursor adapter to add the tag when it is populating the view. For the methods you have to override, just call the super method and then add your own code to set the tag to the view created.

Comment: ok so I tried setting a tag in the `bindView` of the adapter with `view.setTag(name)` name is a string from the cursor but when I click on the checkbox and the `onclick` gets called I get a `NullPointer` on the `Object name = view.getTag()`. did I do that right?